Detailed conservation of enstrophy in 2D turbulence
I have been trying to work through R. H. Kraichnan's seminal 1967 paper on two-dimensional turbulence [Inertial Ranges in Two-Dimensional Turbulence, Phys. Fluids 10, 1417–1423 (1967)].
He starts from the Navier-Stokes equations
$$\partial_t u_i + (u_j \partial_j) u_i = -\partial_i p + \nu\partial_j^2 u_i$$
within a 2D periodic box of side length $D$, along with the incompressibility condition
$$\partial_j u_j = 0$$
(summation over repeated indices is implied). In Fourier space, he obtains an expression for the transfer function $T(k,p,q) = T(k,q,p)$, which governs the transfer of energy between different Fourier modes:
$$T(k,p,q) = 2\pi k\, \mathrm{Im}\left[ \frac{2\pi}{ |\sin(\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})|}(D/2\pi)^4 \cdot (k_m \delta_{ij} + k_j \delta_{im} ) \langle u_i^*(\mathbf{k}) u_j(\mathbf{p}) u_m(\mathbf{q}) \rangle \right]$$
for $\mathbf{k} = \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{q}$ and $T(k,p,q) = 0$ otherwise (i.e. $T=0$  if the three vectors do not form a triangle).
I am stuck on Eq. (2.5), where he states two important properties of $T$:
$$T(k,p,q) + T(p,q,k) + T(q,k,p) = 0 \tag{1}$$
and
$$k^2 T(k,p,q) + p^2 T(p,q,k) + q^2 T(q,k,p) = 0 \tag{2}$$
which can apparently be proven "using incompressibility and the plane-triangle identities" (which I assume means laws of sines and cosines). Physically, the first result shows that energy is conserved for each wavenumber interaction and the second shows that enstrophy is conserved for each interaction (a property unique to 2D).
I can see (I think) how one can prove (1) simply by using the Fourier transform of the incompressibility equation, and noting that $u_i^*(\mathbf{k}) = u_i(-\mathbf{k})$ since it's the Fourier transform of a real function. However I'm struggling to see how one proves (2). Any insight would be appreciated.

I managed to figure this out, so posting an answer in case anyone else gets stuck on it.
Eq. (1) is reasonably straightforward to prove; the easiest way I found  to show it is by first noting that $\mathbf{u}^*(\mathbf{k}) = \mathbf{u}(-\mathbf{k})$ since $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{k})$ is a Hermitian function (i.e. it is  the Fourier transform of a real-valued function). One is then also free to redefine $\mathbf{k} \rightarrow -\mathbf{k}$. The net effect on $T(k,p,q)$ is that the conjugation on $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{k})$ can be dropped in exchange for a minus sign, and the triangle constraint becomes
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{k} + \mathbf{p} + \mathbf{q} = \mathbf{0}. \tag{3}  
\end{equation}
After simplifying the Kronecker delta's, one is then left with permutations of terms such as
$$ (k_j u_j(\mathbf{p}) ) (u_m(\mathbf{k}) u_m(\mathbf{q}) ) - \mathrm{c.c} \tag{4}$$ where $\mathrm{c.c}$ is the complex conjugate. The other factors in $T(k,p,q)$ may be ignored (the constants cancel and so do the terms such as $k/|\sin (\mathbf{p},\mathbf{q})|$ by the law of sines).
Then the Fourier transform of the incompressibility condition
$$ k_j u_j(\mathbf{k}) = 0, \tag{5} $$
combined with (3), allows one to make replacements such as $k_j u_j(\mathbf{p}) = - q_j u_j(\mathbf{p})$ etc. Then Eq. (1) follows straightforwardly by the cancellation of the various terms of the form specified in Eq. (4).
Eq. (2) is more involved, but can be seen  by noting that the incompressibility condition strongly constrains the form of $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{k})$, since it must be orthogonal to $\mathbf{k}$. Writing $\mathbf{k} = (k_x,k_y)^T =  k (\cos \theta_k, \sin \theta_k)^T$, where $\theta_k$ is the angle of the vector $\mathbf{k}$ and $k$ is its magnitude, it can then be shown that $\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{k})$ must be of the form
$$ \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{k}) = |\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{k})| e^{i \phi(\mathbf{k})} \left( \begin{matrix} \mp\sin \theta_k \\ \pm\cos \theta_k \end{matrix} \right) $$
Where $\phi(\mathbf{k})$ is a complex phase, which must satisfy $\phi(\mathbf{k}) + \phi(-\mathbf{k}) = \pi$ by the Hermitian property but is otherwise arbitrary. We are free to choose the upper solution and absorb the other solution into the complex phase, since it only differs by a minus sign. It follows that
$$ k_j u_j(\mathbf{p}) = k | \mathbf{u}(\mathbf{p})| e^{i\phi(\mathbf{k})} \sin (\theta_k - \theta_p)$$
and
$$ u_m(\mathbf{k}) u_m(\mathbf{q}) =  |\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{k})| |\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{q})| e^{i (\phi(\mathbf{p}) + \phi(\mathbf{q}))} \cos(\theta_k - \theta_q)$$
The arguments of the trigonometric functions are the external angles of the triangle:

and may be related to the internal angles through $\sin(\theta_p-\theta_k) = \sin Q$, $\cos(\theta_p - \theta_k) = - \cos Q$, etc. Expanding Eq. (2) reduces down to verifying that
$$A \left\{ (k^2-p^2) k \sin P \cos Q + (p^2 -q^2) p \sin Q \cos K + (q^2-k^2) \sin K \cos P \right\} = 0 \tag{6} $$
where $A = |\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{k})||\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{p})||\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{q})| \sin [\phi(\mathbf{k}) + \phi(\mathbf{p})+\phi(\mathbf{q})]$. The last step is then to use the law of cosines
$$\cos Q = \frac{k^2 +p^2 - q^2}{2kp},$$
etc. The sine terms in Eq. (6) then once again cancel by the law of sines, and the remaining quartic polynomial in $\{k,p,q\}$ cancels.
I can certainly see why this article notes that Kraichnan's paper contains a "very dense presentation"!

Thanks for taking the time to write your solution. I spent some time trying to derive it when you posted it, but to no avail!

No worries ---  glad I'm not the only one who found this difficult!
